# Helium package can't find Chrome binary

Tags: python, selenium, helium

I have installed selenium and helium packages and I am using pythom 3.8.3 on Windows 10 64 Bit
And when trying these lines

```
from helium import *

url = 'https://www.moi.gov.kw/'
browser = start_chrome(url)
```

And I got this traceback

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py in start(self)
     71             cmd.extend(self.command_line_args())
---> 72             self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
     73                                             close_fds=platform.system() != 'Windows',

~\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, encoding, errors, text)
    853 
--> 854             self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
    855                                 pass_fds, cwd, env,

~\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, unused_restore_signals, unused_start_new_session)
   1306             try:
-> 1307                 hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
   1308                                          # no special security

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\helium\_impl\__init__.py in _start_chrome_driver(self, headless, options)
    101                 try:
--> 102                         result = Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    103                 except WebDriverException:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py in __init__(self, executable_path, port, options, service_args, desired_capabilities, service_log_path, chrome_options, keep_alive)
     72             log_path=service_log_path)
---> 73         self.service.start()
     74 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py in start(self)
     80             if err.errno == errno.ENOENT:
---> 81                 raise WebDriverException(
     82                     "'%s' executable needs to be in PATH. %s" % (

WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-3b7004c73d33> in <module>
      2 
      3 url = 'https://www.moi.gov.kw/'
----> 4 browser = start_chrome(url)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\helium\__init__.py in start_chrome(url, headless, options)
    127                 kill_browser()
    128     """
--> 129         return _get_api_impl().start_chrome_impl(url, headless, options)
    130 
    131 def go_to(url):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\helium\_impl\__init__.py in start_chrome_impl(self, url, headless, options)
     95                 return result
     96         def start_chrome_impl(self, url=None, headless=False, options=None):
---> 97                 chrome_driver = self._start_chrome_driver(headless, options)
     98                 return self._start(chrome_driver, url)
     99         def _start_chrome_driver(self, headless, options):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\helium\_impl\__init__.py in _start_chrome_driver(self, headless, options)
    104                         # This usually happens when chromedriver is not on the PATH.
    105                         driver_path = self._use_included_web_driver('chromedriver')
--> 106                         result = Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=driver_path)
    107                 atexit.register(self._kill_service, result.service)
    108                 return result

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py in __init__(self, executable_path, port, options, service_args, desired_capabilities, service_log_path, chrome_options, keep_alive)
     74 
     75         try:
---> 76             RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
     77                 self,
     78                 command_executor=ChromeRemoteConnection(

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in __init__(self, command_executor, desired_capabilities, browser_profile, proxy, keep_alive, file_detector, options)
    155             warnings.warn("Please use FirefoxOptions to set browser profile",
    156                           DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)
--> 157         self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
    158         self._switch_to = SwitchTo(self)
    159         self._mobile = Mobile(self)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in start_session(self, capabilities, browser_profile)
    250         parameters = {"capabilities": w3c_caps,
    251                       "desiredCapabilities": capabilities}
--> 252         response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
    253         if 'sessionId' not in response:
    254             response = response['value']

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Windows NT 10.0.10240 x86_64)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used such lines and the problem solved.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.binary_location = "C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"
browser = start_chrome(url, headless=False, options=options)
```